# Azure app service environment inbound and outbound ip

Tags: azure

I am very new to azure app service environment v3. I created the ASEV3 with internal load balancer and hosted my python function app. When i checked the configuration, i noticed that it has an inbound ip address from my Vnet/Subnet and outbound public VIP. My question is when the app will do a outbound connection to resource local to the Vnet, how the connection will established as the outbound address is public.